# add more than one control from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, addition

what I want to do is to add more than one control from code behind to my website, I know how to add one control, but I want to add two controls at the same time, when someone click on an other button!

here is my code, but it only add the second button!

```
protected void Unnamed2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          Button b = new Button();
          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
          {
              b.ID = i.ToString();
              b.Text = i.ToString();
              b.Width=250;
              b.Height = 100;
              b.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
             Page.Form.Controls.Add(b);

          }
      }
```

Comment: Move the `new` in the `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new Button()` also needs to be in the loop... otherwise you only create one instance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.ID = i.ToString();
    b.Text = i.ToString();
    b.Width=250;
    b.Height = 100;
    b.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
    Page.Form.Controls.Add(b);
}
```